# Biztalk orchestration gets triggered by file adapter ahead of trigger message

Tags: scheduled-tasks, biztalk

We are trying to use the scheduled task adapter for triggering orchestration. Using the code sample linked below the adapter does not wait for the scheduled time to process order files, it processes the orders as soon as they are available. We are using the version 4.0 of the adapter on Biztalk 2010. Any help or sugesstion would be greatly appreciated.

BizTalk Scheduled Task Adapter
https://biztalkscheduledtask.codeplex.com/

BizTalk Server : Scheduling Orchestration using Trigger Message
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25101.biztalk-server-scheduling-orchestration-using-trigger-message.aspx

Comment: I solved the problem myself by removing and adding the correlation types. There must have been a wrong setting in the Project.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the File Adapter, it looks like you are getting the expected result as the File Adapter will receive the file as soon as it's available.

With the Scheduled Task Adapter, you have to use the FileStreamProvider to receive the file at the scheduled time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm familiar with the Scheduled Task adapter but if you want that a receive port picks up files during a part of the day => you can use the service window on the receive location.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559260.aspx

Or do you have a different scenario in mind?